# Generate a java-usable regex negating a word in a precise position

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've seen similar questions, but not exactly the same: My problem is that I want to generate a java-usable regex for a 311 characters string that not has some characters in precise positions:

The intuitive solution is something like this:

```
(.{104})(^OM)M(.{204})
```

but I know that if I have to negate whole words I must use lookahead:

```
(.{104})(?:(?!OM))M(.{204})
```

This RE neither works.

Ideas?

Remember that the regex has only to match when the positions 105 and 106 of the string are distinct from "OM" and the position 107 is equals to "M".

Yes, I can only do this with a regex and yes I cannot use neither `^` nor `$`.

Best regards.

Comment: Do you really need a regex here?

Comment: Can character 105 be "O" as long as 106 is not "M" (and vice versa)?

Comment: Why can't you use `^` and `$`?

Comment: So `...OMM...` and `OMN` and `ZEN` should not match, but `ORM` and `RMM` and `ZEM` should match?

Comment: Yes, I have to use a regex, I am using an application that allows me to filter text registers with regex. Right, Character 105 can be "O" if 106 is another thing. And right OMM should not math, OMN shouldn't match, ZEN shouldn't match. ORM, RMM and ZEM should match.

Comment: @minyatur - `I cannot use neither ^ nor $`. Without using these anchors, `positions 105 and 106 of the string are distinct from "OM" and the position 107 is equals to "M"` is meaningless, because on a line longer than 311, the match position will shift to satisfy that restriction.

Answer (score 2):

I won't use a regex for this task. Simply using String API would do the job:

```
str.length() == 311 && !str.substring(104, 106).equals("OM") && str.charAt(106) == 'M'
```

If you only want to use regex, then you have to modify your regex a little bit. You are checking for `OM` using negative look-behind, but ignoring the next 2 characters. You actually need to match them, if they are not `OM`:

```
(.{104})(?:(?!OM)..)M(.{204})
```

Comment: This seems to work, I have to do more tests and it is slow because I am using an application that executes the regex (I have not access to the code to do massive tests). I'll tell you. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. I tested on Perl, works there.

```
 #   "(?s)^(.{104})((?!.?OM)..M)(.{204})$"


 (?s)                 # Dot-all modifier
 ^                    # BOS
 ( .{104} )           # (1), any characters, positions 1-104
 (                    # (2 start)
      (?! .? OM )          # not 'OM' in position 105 nor 106
      . .                  # grab char 105,106
      M                    # 'M' in position 107
 )                    # (2 end)
 ( .{204} )           # (3), any characters, positions 108-311
 $                    # EOS
```

This is an alternative if strict number of characters include line endings that could be `\r\n` and should be counted as two chars.

`"\\A([\\S\\s]{104})((?![\\S\\s]?OM)[\\S\\s][\\S\\s]M)([\\S\\s]{204})\\z"`